# Exception "A condition specified dynamically has an unexpected format" with RFC_READ_TABLE

Tags: sap-dotnet-connector, saprfc

I'm using .Net Sap Connector 3 and function "RFC_READ_TABLE" to read PA0001 table data.

Where condition I'm using seem stupid, but it's only to explain that my problem is the length of this expression.

If I use:

```
MANDT = '100' OR MANDT = '100' OR MANDT = '100' OR MANDT = '100'
```

it work. But if I use

```
MANDT = '100' OR MANDT = '100' OR MANDT = '100' OR MANDT = '100' OR MANDT = '100'
```

I have this exception: "A condition specified dynamically has an unexpected format".

I tried to break the string with the character ~ and specify this character as a separator

function.SetValue ("DELIMITER", "~")

but the problem persists

Help me!

Comment: I found the problem. WHere condition cannot exceeds 72 chars :(

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: Resolved! In code you have to split where-condition and add every item generated

IRfcTable inputTableOptions = function.GetTable("OPTIONS");

string[] aWhere = sWhereExpression.Split("~".ToCharArray());

foreach (string cond in aWhere)
{
    inputTableOptions.Append();
    inputTableOptions.SetValue("TEXT", cond);
}

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Adding OP's comment as an answer to help future visitors:

`OPTIONS` line has a 72 char limitation, so if one has a long condition the solution would be to split it into several lines:

```
inputTableOptions = function.GetTable("OPTIONS"); 
string[] aWhere = sWhereExpression.Split("~".ToCharArray()); foreach (string cond in aWhere) { inputTableOptions.Append(); 
inputTableOptions.SetValue("TEXT", cond);
```